# How can I get an instance of a base class from an inherited class dynamically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've got a class public class foubar : fou

fou has its properties and so does foubar
I've created an instance of foubar and set values to all the properties including the base classes'.
Now I need an instance of fou that has the property values that are in foubar.
True, I could create a new instance of fou and write code that would populate this new instance from a foubar instance but that means I have to change to code every time the base class properties change.

I'd like something that would work like this, where FB is an instance of foubar

fou test = (fou) FB;

This "works" in C#, but test is really type foubar. I need only fou, nothing else,

I want a way to dynamically return an instance of a base class populated from the data/instance of the derived class.

Ideas?

Comment: Why do you need it to *only* be the base class?

Comment: Why do you need the real type to be fou ? Seems very "unobject" to me...

Comment: I've got a method that only takes type fou, won't take foubar.
The base class fou and the method that takes fou are out of my control.

Comment: Well, a method with a fou parameter will accept to recieve a foubar value... it's basic object

Comment: That method should take descendants of `fou`, including your `foubar` - it sounds like you're trying to solve the wrong problem...

Comment: ...it might help if you expand your question to include the rationale (including errors when you do pass down your inherited object)

Comment: fou is an entity framework class, it really represents a table
foubar is my wrapper around it derived from fou
when I try to do context.AddTofou(FB); it doesn't accept a foubar object, even with a cast; it wants fou.

Comment: entity framwork error thrown: 
  Message="Object mapping could not be found for Type with identity 'foubar'."
  Source="System.Data.Entity"

Comment: Don't know much about EF ;o( How about using composition over inheritance ?

Comment: You should really put more context in your question, specially the fact that you're using EF

Comment: You are certainly trying to solve the wrong problem. If foubar inherits from fou *in your entity model* then you certainly can call context.AddTofou(FB), because inherited types and their parents have the same entity set. Since you say you can't, I suspect your mapping is not right.

Answer (score 2):

I used reflection to dynamically make a copy of the base class' fields.
Got this from: [C# Using Reflection to copy base class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198886/c-using-reflection-to-copy-base-class-properties)
Now I have a true fou type I can pass to EF.

```
private fou GetBaseData(foubar FB)
        {
            fou test_fou = new fou();
            Type type = FB.GetType();
            type = type.BaseType;
            UpdateForType(type, FB, test_fou);
            return test_fou;
        }

        private static void UpdateForType(Type type, foubar source, fou destination)
        {
            FieldInfo[] myObjectFields = type.GetFields(
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (FieldInfo fi in myObjectFields)
            {
                fi.SetValue(destination, fi.GetValue(source));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why do you need such a thing? But you can do something like this:

```
class Foo 
{
    // ...

    public Foo ConcreteFoo()
    {
        if (this.GetType().Equals(typeof(Foo)))
            return this;
        else
        {
            Foo f = new Foo();
            // clone properties
            return f;
        }
    }
}
```

So you can do:

```
FouBar foobar = new FooBar();
Foo f = foobar.ConcreteFoo();
```

I'm really not comfortable with this ... Is there any special reason why you want a concrete `Foo`?

*(edit)*

Following the comments I can see that your problem is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572210/nullreferenceexception-when-calling-insertonsubmit-in-linq-to-sql/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection and generics to map like-named properties to eachother, but I don't think you can change the base type of an object without cloning or instantiating a new one.