# [LINQ]InsertOnSubmit NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, linq, insertonsubmit

I have a rather annoying issue with LinqToSql. I have created a class that is derived from the class in the DataContext.

The problem is that as soon as I use "InsertOnSubmit(this);" on this derived class I get a NullReferenceException.

I've seen some people with the same issue. However they've used a custom constructor and solved the issue by calling ": this()" like this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/0cf1fccb-6398-4f16-920b-adef9dc4ac9f

The difference is that I use a default constructor which causes the base constructor to be called so there should not be any problem!

Could someone please help me with this, starts to get annoying!

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post the stack trace you get with the exception is thrown?  This is the best starting point for figuring out an exception.

Comment: Sure!
 InsertOnSubmit(TEntity entity) MDK.Security.Messaging.Message.Send() in E:\Users\Kurt\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MDK\MDK.Security\Messaging\Message.cs: line 62 MDK.Tests.MessagingTests.UsersCanSendMessages() in E:\Users\Kurt\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MDK\MDK.Tests\MessagingTests.cs: line 89

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499436/linq-insertonsubmit-nullreferenceexception, among others. They all have one of two solutions, depending on if it's a partial or derived class.

Comment: I saw that one Richard Hein, however they either create a partial class(which I do not want to do) or they use ": this()" which I have done without further success

Answer (score 0):

This is one way: [https://stackoverflow.com/....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572210/nullreferenceexception-when-calling-insertonsubmit-in-linq-to-sql/1572963#1572963)

If you just want to pre-populate some fields, an alternative might be:

```
partial class MyLinqClass {
    string Text = "Default";

    public MyLinqClass AsOne() {
        Text = "One";
        ...
        return this;
    }
}

var x = new MyLinqClass().AsOne();
context.InsertOnSubmit(x); // x is type MyLinqClass
```