# Unable to typecast to LinQ Entity base class

Tags: c#

I have generated LinQ to SQL entity classes using the generator in Visual Studio 2010.

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Address")]
    public partial class Address : INotifyPropertyChanging,INotifyPropertyChanged     
   { 
        //all the generated methods are here
   }
```

Then I create an Interface  ITask

```
  public Interface ITask
  {
      //some interface methods go here
  }
```

Finally I create my class

```
class myclass : Address, ITask
{
    //implement interface methods
}
```

Elsewhere in my unit tests
I create a myclass object the following happens

```
    myclass temp=new myclass();
    Address adr=(Address)temp;
    adr.GetType();//returns myclass when I watch the var in debugger
    DataContext dc=new DataContext();//the linq data context
    dc.Addresses.InsertOnSubmit(adr);//Object reference not set 
    //to an instance of an object NullReferenceException
    ITask task=(ITask)temp;
    temp.Callinterfacemethods();//works fine, iam able to call interface methods
```

I am a C++ programmer, this is part of my first C# assignment. What am I doing wrong? The above would be perfectly valid in C++.

Thanks.

David

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499436/linq-insertonsubmit-nullreferenceexception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499436/linq-insertonsubmit-nullreferenceexception)

Comment: Try to use Address adr = temp as Address; if (adr != null) { doSomething(); }. Please look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Malcome O'Hare - That link shows me how to overcome the problem ie extending the partial class.It does not answer why inheriting the class does not work(as explained in my question above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this feature ie inheriting a linq entity class is not supported currently and I was thinking that my understanding of OOAD was flawed!

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/310798/linq-to-sql-nullreferenceexception-when-attaching-inherited-record